# Calculating the difference between first and last value of a comma separated list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an example ordered comma separated list in a cell. Values are comma separated. they can be 1 digit or 2 digits.

```
A1: 3,4,5,10
```

I'm trying to get the difference between the first value and the last value.
This is what I tried to do:

```
B1: = RIGHT(A1,1)-LEFT(A1,1)
```

This works fine if all the values are single digit, but if the last value is two digits, then it doesn't give the correct result.

Is there a better way of writing this formula which works fine both for single and double digits? please.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below formula.

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",", REPT(" ",100)),100))-LEFT(A1,SEARCH(",",A1)-1)
```

[image]

It will work for any length digit, even for decimal values also.